# How does Dr. Rajesh Koothrappali talk in the cafateria?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, the-big-bang-theory

As seen [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/85305/whats-the-exact-problem-with-raj), Dr. Rajesh Koothrappali is unable to talk to women or to other men in the presence of women unless he is intoxicated or has taken a pill or something.

However many episodes feature the main characters in the cafeteria together, where you can clearly see other women in the background and Raj does not seem to have any problem talking to the rest of the guys - how is he able to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Raj doesn't have problem talking when they are many and mixed in crowd.

From Bat Jar Conjecture (S01E13)

> Penny: You know, it’s none of my business, but isn’t a guy who can’t speak in front of women going to hold you back a little?
>
> Leonard: Oh, uh, **he’ll be okay once the women are mixed into the crowd. He only has a problem when they’re one on one** and smell nice.

<sub>[Source](https://bigbangtrans.wordpress.com/series-1-episode-13-the-bat-jar-conjecture/)</sub>

So, it's clear that he doesn't have problem talking when women are mixed into the crowd. He only has this problem when they're one on one.

However, there is a big spoiler ahead.

> His psychological fear for women, due to which he is not able to talk to them, does get cured around season 6.